# cancel destructor calls in operator delete[]

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, operator-overloading, delete-operator

I'm writing a memory leak detector that creates a text file with some warnings. For example, it generates a warning when `delete` is used instead of `delete[]` to free the memory allocated using `new[]`.

What I find difficult is the same thing vice versa, when using `delete[]` on an object created with `new`. In that case, the destructor is called for a number of objects that have never been constructed.

Here's something from the c++ reference:

> ... delete[] is an operator with a very specific behavior: An expression
>   with the delete[] operator, first calls the appropriate destructors
>   for each element in the array (if these are of a class type) ...

My question is, can I do something about it? Calling the destructor for objects that haven't actually been created often causes a segfault. I'd like to somehow "catch" it, cancel the deletion of an array and create a warning.

EDIT: Seems there's not much I can do. Checked another board and got the advice to use a memory allocator, which is overkill for my memory leak detector, and/or look into how valgrind operates. I might do the latter.

Comment: It is possible to define your own `delete` operator - this was done in the _Cube_ _2_ _Sauerbraten_ game.

Comment: overload delete operator

Comment: My first idea was to overwrite the delete operator. I'm not sure if overloading is even possible, except placement delete. Anyway, the delete statement first calls the destructors for each element in an array (probably causing a segfault when wrong), then the actual operator delete for each element.

Comment: The designated object(s) are destroyed before operator delete is called; there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do anything, because if the client code calls `delete`, when the operator new was `new []`, you probably won't receive the same address in the delete operator.

Comment: How could the address help?

Comment: @user3545224 The compiler needs the address to pass to the `operator new` function.